# How to ensure that my iOS app has a valid access token for use with the Instagram API

Tags: ios, api, oauth, instagram, access-token

I'm building an iOS app that will use instagram photos in a slide show as the background of the app.

What I want to do is just set up a specific account that I can upload pictures to, and then the app will pull in the most recent photos from this account.

So far, I've set up the account and have been able to generate an access token manually by inserting my client id and redirect URI into this URL

```
https://instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[CLIENT_ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]&response_type=code
```

However, I've read that the access token generated from following this procedure is not permanent. I do not want the users of my app to ever see the authentication going on in the background. They themselves will never actually login into Instagram.

What would be the best way of making sure my app is always authenticated at launch and that the access token is always valid?

Thanks

Comment: Please split up your posts in paragraphs, and use some formatting.  See my editing.  Also, the title does not match the actual title.  I hope this helps, and not annoys you.

Comment: What do you mean by "the title does not match the actual title?" Thanks for the input, I'll reformat it.

Comment: Well, your question is about authentication, and not about one photo, and neither about making an Instagram app. The title should better be a brief version of your question. Enjoy building this app, sorry I can't help you technically on this, and happy New Year!

Comment: No problem! I appreciate your inputs. The better my post looks, the more likely I am to get a response. So thanks and happy New Year to you as well!

Comment: You need to run your own HTTPS API to provide the token to your app.  You should use SSL Pinning, otherwise someone will steal your token using a man in the middle attack.

Comment: Yea that was what I was afraid of. I didn't know if there was a method to do it in-app, say in viewDidLoad or in the application delegate. I'll look into rolling my own API. Whoever developed this website [link](http://jelled.com/instagram/access-token) seems to have accomplished this,so I'll give it a shot as well

Answer (score 0):

A typical OAuth flow has the resource owner (a user) approve or deny requests from a client application. When you first got an access token, you had to complete a form approving access to Intsagram by your app.

Since you want to hide the auth_server/resource_owner interaction from your end users, you'll have to automate the role of the resource owner.  The access token should tell you when it expires.  Since it's your redirection endpoint that has the access token, that's where you'll need code to detect the token will soon expire and request a new one.  Your code will need to

1. Simulate a request from the client app by going to https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT-ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT-URI&response_type=code
2. Respond to the HTML page that is returned. Approve the request.
3. The server will respond with an authorization code that you can exchange for
   a new access token.

There are some hoops to jump through because OAuth is designed for the resource owner to approve or deny each request.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something along these lines. I may write some server code to cache images from the Instagram API, and then just have my app hit my server when it needs new images. That way I minimize the risk of running out of api requests(I believe there's a limit per hour).Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would want to do this by logging into the target account because having your app's user log in to Instagram as the account you are talking about may be unnecessary.

While I am not an expert on the Instagram API, it looks like you can avoid using an access token for getting the feed of a particular user.

Here is some support for this:

> Do you need to authenticate?
>
> For the most part, Instagram’s API only requires the use of a client_id. A client_id simply associates your server, script, or program with a specific application. However, some requests require authentication - specifically requests made on behalf of a user. Authenticated requests require an access_token. These tokens are unique to a user and should be stored securely. Access tokens may expire at any time in the future.

http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/

If a client ID is only associated with your application and does not require the user to authenticate, it appears that this endpoint should work:

> GET /users/user-id/media/recent
>
> https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/3/media/recent/?client_id=YOUR-CLIENT_ID
>
> The functionality is the same with the previous one, but use client_id
> instead of access_token
>
> PARAMETERS
>
> COUNT Count of media to return.
>
> MAX_TIMESTAMP Return media before this UNIX timestamp.
>
> MIN_TIMESTAMP Return media after this UNIX timestamp.
>
> MIN_ID Return media later than this min_id. CLIENT_ID A valid client id.
>
> MAX_ID    Return media earlier than this max_id.

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users_media_recent_with_client_id

Comment: I did try this, but I believe I ran into an issue where the Instagram API would only let me make so many calls per hour. Do you know if there are any limits using only the CLIENT_ID?

Comment: You are limited to 5000 requests by client id OR access token per hour. http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/  Thus, the result would be the same if you used a single account across all instances of your application as it would with just the client ID, since all users would be counted against the account's limit.  If you need to go beyond that limit, you will need to authenticate individual users.